# Why does loop end on the "else" of the if statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

loops stops on the else part of the if statement.. otherwise runs great. What code does is looks to see if list of employees from department is on the schedule (day 1 of date range. then day 2 of date range and so on. so if no records are found code adds all list of employees for each day of date range(user selected). My issue comes when 1 employee is already on the schedule then all loops stop.

```
Private Sub Command37_Click()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strPrompt As String
    
    Dim str2Prompt As String
    Dim str3Prompt As String
    Dim startd As String
    Dim endd As String
strPrompt = InputBox("Enter date to copy")
str2Prompt = InputBox("Enter Start Date")
str3Prompt = InputBox("Enter End Date")

str3Prompt = DateAdd("d", 1, str3Prompt)
'trying this
   
While DateDiff("d", str2Prompt, str3Prompt) > 0
   
        strSQL = "SELECT Employee.[Employee] FROM Employee WHERE Class ='" & Me.Text0 & "' AND Active = -1"
        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        Dim existrste As String
        Dim sqlexist As String




        With rst
               Do While Not .EOF
               
               say = rst![Employee]
               'MsgBox say
               
               
        
        'see if exist
               sqlexist = "SELECT Employee FROM [Daily Report] WHERE FORMAT([Start Shift],'Short Date') ='" & str2Prompt & "' AND Employee ='" & say & "'"
               DoCmd.RunSQL sqlexist
               Set rste = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlexist)
               existrste = rste![Employee]
              
               If existrste = "" Then
                        Dim Nendd As Date
                        
                       'MsgBox "Insert" & say
                       'select from dailyreport where date is userinput date to copy
                        stgcopy = "SELECT * FROM [Daily Report] WHERE format([Start Shift],'Short Date') ='" & strPrompt & "' AND Employee ='" & say & "'"
                        DoCmd.RunSQL stgcopy
                        Set rstc = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(stgcopy)
                        
                        'end time format
                        endd = rstc![End Shift]
                        enddt = TimeValue(endd)
                        Nendd = str2Prompt & " " & enddt
                        'start time format
                        sd = rstc![Start Shift]
                        sdt = TimeValue(sd)
                        Nsd = str2Prompt & " " & sdt
                        'class
                        clss = rstc![Class]
                        'billable
                        bill = rstc![Billable]
                        'status
                        sta = rstc![Status]
                        'Company
                        Comp = rstc![Company]
                        'Lease
                        Leas = rstc![Lease]
                        'Well
                        Well = rstc![Well]
                        'dont include transfer
                        tran = rstc![Transfer]
                        
                        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        
                        SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO `Daily Report` (`Employee`,`Class`,`Start Shift`,`End Shift`,`Billable`,`Status`,`Company`,`Lease`,`Well`) Values('" & say & "','" & clss & "','" & Nsd & "','" & Nendd & "','" & bill & "','" & sta & "','" & Comp & "','" & Leas & "','" & Well & "') "
                        DoCmd.RunSQL SQLINSERT
                        'rstc.MoveNext
                        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
                        MsgBox str2Prompt
                Else
                End If
            
               rst.MoveNext
               
               Loop
             'trying this
                        str2Prompt = DateAdd("d", 1, str2Prompt)
               rst.Close
               'Make sure you close the recordset...
        
         End With


Wend



End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you even *have* an `else` if it does nothing?

Comment: Did it reach EOF?

Comment: RunSQL is not useful for a SELECT query, only SQL action statements. That line does nothing productive. Do you allow empty string in text fields? If Employee field is empty is it an empty string or is it Null? Have you step debugged?

Comment: paxdiable - if data exist on that date for that employee then do nothing and skip insert

Comment: braX - it did not reach EOF, it stopped the loop once it found data on date for an employee

Comment: June7 - i tried "if result is null" but it did nothing. i will try now that most of the code is working and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after something like this (air code):

```vb
Private Sub Command37_Click()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim rst         As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL      As String
    Dim Prompt1     As Date    
    Dim Prompt2     As Date
    Dim Prompt3     As Date
    Dim Nendd       As Date
    Dim Nsd         As Date
    Dim clss        As String
    Dim sta         As String
    Dim comp        As String
    Dim leas        As String
    Dim well        As String
    Dim existrste   As Boolean
    Dim sqlexist    As String

    Prompt1 = DateValue(InputBox("Enter date to copy"))
    Prompt2 = DateValue(InputBox("Enter Start Date"))
    Prompt3 = DateValue(InputBox("Enter End Date"))

    Prompt3 = DateAdd("d", 1, Prompt3)
    While DateDiff("d", Prompt2, Prompt3) > 0   
        strSQL = "SELECT Employee.[Employee] FROM Employee WHERE Class ='" & Me!Text0.Value & "' AND Active = -1"
        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        With rst
            Do While Not .EOF            
                say = rst![Employee].Value
                'MsgBox say
                'see if exist
                sqlexist = "SELECT Employee FROM [Daily Report] WHERE Fix([Start Shift]) = #" & Format(Prompt2, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "" AND Employee ='" & say & "'"
                Set rste = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlexist)
                existrste = CBool(rste.RecordCount)
                
                If Not existrste Then                        
                    'MsgBox "Insert" & say
                    'select from dailyreport where date is userinput date to copy
                    stgcopy = "SELECT * FROM [Daily Report] WHERE Fix([Start Shift]) =#" & Format(Prompt1, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "" AND Employee ='" & say & "'"
                    Set rstc = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(stgcopy)
                    
                    Nendd = Prompt2 + TimeValue(rstc![End Shift].Value)
                    Nsd = Prompt2 +TimeValue(rstc![Start Shift].Value)
                    'class
                    clss = rstc![Class].Value
                    'billable
                    bill = rstc![Billable].Value
                    'status
                    sta = rstc![Status].Value
                    'Company
                    Comp = rstc![Company].Value
                    'Lease
                    Leas = rstc![Lease].Value
                    'Well
                    Well = rstc![Well].Value

                    rstc.AddNew
                    rstc!Employee.Value = say
                    rstc![Class].Value = clss
                    rstc![Start Shift].Value = Nsd
                    rstc![End Shift].Value = neendd
                    rstc!Billable.Value = bill
                    rstc![Status].Value = sta
                    rstc!Company.Value = Comp
                    rstc!Lease.Value = Leas
                    rstc!Well.Value = Well
                    rstc.Update
                    MsgBox Prompt2
                End If            
                rst.MoveNext               
            Loop
            Prompt2 = DateAdd("d", 1, Prompt2)
        End With
        rst.Close
    Wend

End Sub
```